# How to access Internet connected Debian Linux computer through SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, beagleboneblack

I have a BeagleBone Black that is running Debian Wheezy. I want to be able to SSH into it over the internet as long as it is connected to the Internet. I want to be able to type in an URL and be able to access it or deploy software on it.

Many other posts showed how one has to configure the router to forward the port and such. However, I want to be able to take this Beaglebone anywhere, maybe even at a coffee shop with Wifi, and I can quickly access it from another computer through the Internet.

I am wondering what is the best approach to do this. I have my own domain name (provider is Namecheap.com), and I won't mind actually paying for some web hosting services if the solution requires that.

To sum it up, I want to be able to SSH into a Debian Linux system via a domain name without any configuration with the network hardware. I want to be able to quickly set it up and access it as long as the system has internet access. How can this be done?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to just use an IP address?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a domain name, but then I thought IP address changes depends on where you go.

Comment: You have a name registered with Namecheap - do they provide dynamic DNS with your registration package
? You could install a DDNS client in the Debian system so that its domain name is updated in Namecheap's DNS, but it wouldn't be instantaneous whenever you wanted to work on it, but could probably be configured in cron to update at bootup.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a "dynamic dns service", since (most likely) your home ip address is not static. it changes with time, which is why it makes sense to use a domain name. However you can not use a normal dns service, since that updates far too slowly.

You need to configure that dynamic dns service such that it points to the current public ip address of your home router. Typically that is done by a trigger that submits the new ip address as soon as the internet connection has been established. So this has to be done from within your home network, typically by a feature of your router (if offered). Alternatively you can use some utility installed on your boards system that is able to detect its public ip address and when that changes. There are some such utilities in the standard repositories. You can *not* simply publish your ip every minute or so. It has to be event driven (on connect), or you will probably be blocked by the dynamic dns service.

Then indeed you have to configure port forwarding on your home router. The rule has to forward all incoming requests to a specific port to your boards port 22. Note: do *not* use port 22 on the outside, so do not forward port 22 to port 22. This works, but you will see constant brute force hacking attacks against your system. Just use something like 50022 or whatever (on the outside!).

That should be all.

---

I take from your comment that you also want to be able to take that board wherever you go and just use any connection wherever. Such thing *is* possible, but much more complex. For certain you do need some additional server you have control over. That server has to play relay and forward your requests to your board which establishes an ssh tunnel between that server and itself as soon as it goes online. So you definitely do need some fixed point somewhere. Such a server is no rocket science. You can rent a virtual one for 3-5 Euros a month these days and do with it whatever you want.

The idea here is that your board contacts that server and establishes an ssh tunnel pointing back to its own port 22. Now you can contact the tunnel which is open at the server and your packages will be forwarded through the tunnel to your board. That works, it is a bit slower than otherwise.

In that case you do *not* need a dynamic dns service, since such a virtual server typically comes with a fixed ip address. So you can simply resolve your domain to that server of yours.

Question in this case is why to do that. Since you already have a comfortable server at your hand, so what is the board for? The only motivation I can think of is to be able to do illegal downloads or hacking attempts in the foreign environment... Which is not an issue in general. Networks are there to be explored. But you clearly should think thrice when you leave the legal ground. Especially about whom you might cause massive troubles :-)

Oh, you could also combine this approach with using your home router instead of a separate server in the internet. Your board can access your home network using the dynamic dns service, contact some system inside your home network which acts just like the rented server described above.

---

Taking the additional information from that next comment you gave also this might be worth a try, though I am not sure if that will work. You will have to give it a try:

If everyone meant to access the board is within the same local network, then you might get along without the need for port forwarding. You could try to use one of the mentioned dynamic dns utilities to publish your *network internal* ip address to the dns service. *If* they accept and publish that address, then everyone should be able to directly access your board inside the local network (so no via the internet), but by using your domain name. I never tried such thing. I could imagine that dns service providers block such thing. But then again, they might not. So it might be worth a try, since it would be a very simple and elegant solution. Also I am not that sure if all systems will accept such an internal address from a dns authority. As said: you will have to try this.

---

There certainly are more theoretical possibilities, but those certainly are much more complex. If you stay near your board you certainly can also use things like bluetooth or similar. You could bundle a cheap and broken smartphone and use it as a modem, that way the board can act just like the home router above. Certainly you have the option of a wifi ad-hock network connection, but I doubt that is what you are looking for.

One thing I would definitely *not* do is use a third party service provider specialized in such things. Something like TeamViewer or similar. I consider these a serious and obvious security thread, despite what they claim themselves. You definitely can never trust a closed source or internet only service, since there is simply no way for you do really check what they do. *So do not fall for that apparently simple and comfortable solution!*

Comment: It doesn't have to be the router -- under Linux it is possible to run a DDNS client directly in the OS as long as it can detect its own public address.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes, I wrote that, didn't I? OK I will be more precise in that point.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but is there a way to do it if I don't have access to the networking equipment? For example, I still want to be able to access it when it is connected to the library's, coffee shops, or other people's home network.

Comment: @tuzzer Ah, you should have said so. That is different and much more complex.

Comment: @tuzzer I added a section to my answer for that second question. Hope that helps :-) Have fun!

Comment: @arkascha Thanks for you answer! Now I have a much better idea how can I set that up. I am really just trying to allow a few people to be able to deploy and test code on a BeagleBone Black which controls a robot. The reason why I wanted it to work over the internet is because I want to be able to work in public places like libraries. Maybe there's a better way to do this?

Comment: @tuzzer Sure, one more variant. I added another section for that as well. Not sure if that works, but it would actually be a very simple solution. So worth a try.

Comment: @tuzzer One thing: _please_, for future questions, please try to make sure that you give _all_ relevant information right inside the question itself. Take your time to write it. The better and more precise the question, the better and more precise the answers. It is a bit annoying to write a long answer only to find out that the actual question you try to get answered is actually different from what you posted... I am sure you can understand that. Thanks!

Comment: @arkacha I have tried publishing my internal IP address and it works well! Thanks! Sorry that my question wasn't clear. I mentioned that I want to be able to access it through the internet in my second paragraph, but I think I should write out my ultimate purpose better.

Comment: @tuzzer Oki, great to hear that you make progress. Good luck!

Comment: i opened ssh port on server firewall and router. i can ssh to server using localhost and using local IP (in LAN). Now, i want to ssh from internet. is ssh port is open for ISP's routers, or any other way? i don't want GUI - like teamviewer and similiar systems - i want CMD access. is VPN can do this?

Comment: I already answered to that in my first update to the question: you want to use a simple relay server that allows your target system to ssh into that and setup a "callback" ssh tunnel with that connection. Then you can connect into that ssh tunnel from the internet using the relay server and your request will com out on that target system that initiated the tunnel setup. Sounds spooky, but works pretty well, actually.